# NSBrowser with sections like Finder in OS X 10.8+

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface, nsbrowser

I have a little problem wich - actually - becomes a bigger problem for me. I want to use a NSBrowser and group the rows in each column. The groups should at least separated by a line or a headline. Equal to the finder in OS X 10.8+, if you switch to the view with rows and sort by kind or programs. BTW, the NSTableView has everything I need, but I couldn't tell NSBrowser to use a NSTableView instance instead of a NSMatrix.

Has anyone an idea how I can tell NSBrowser to group the row-items?

Answer (score 1):

Well...you could do an ugly hack where you subclass NSMatrix, and make it work completely differently, and then wedge it into an NSBrowser.

But, honestly, NSBrowser is a super-old class and hasn’t gotten any love in seven years or so. It’s going to be a lot of pain, I’d imagine you’re much better off making your own, based on NSTableViews.

Comment: Well - you as longer as I think about that, I come to the same conclusion. I'm going to check out how to realize my needs with NSTableView.